# How to display the time in 24-hour format using Struts 2

Tags: jsp, time, struts2, datetimepicker, struts2-jquery

I'm using Struts 2 and want to display time in the 24-hour format, but it is showing in the 12-hour format.

```jsp
<sx:datetimepicker name="LoginTime" 
                   type="time" 
                   displayFormat = "HH:mm" 
                   label="Login Time(HH:MM 24hours format)" />
```

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format **`"HH"`** is used in Java for 24 hours, **`"hh"`** for 12 hours.

As of `sx:` prefix commonly used for Struts2 Dojo tags, you'd better replace it with `"sj:"` and [Struts2 jQuery plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=119537#content/view/119537). It is using its own format for displaying the value. [The DatePicker widget](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag) `displayFormat` attribute should be used to define the format of the date. If it doesn't fit the required format you have also an option to format the value in topic. To display a date and time you need a [timepicker addon](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag#datepicker-with-timepicker-addon).

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<html>
  <head>
    <sj:head locale="de" jquerytheme="lightness"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:form id="form" theme="xhtml">
      <sj:datetimepicker name="LoginTime" timepicker="true" timepickerOnly="true"  timepickerFormat="hh:mm" label="Login Time(HH:MM 24hours format)"/>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *The format "HH" is used in Java for 12 hours, "hh" for 24 hours.* - Are you sure?

Comment: So if hh is for 12 and OP wants 24 then why do you use hh?

Comment: Let the OP try this answer and post his/her comments.